# How to convert a Image file to Asset Image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the **image_picker** and **image_cropper** plugin to select or capture the image with the help of the camera and Gallery. I got an image file from an **image_picker**. Now, I am using the **Image.asset() widget** to show the image in the **Circle Avatar**. Can anyone please tell me how I convert an image File to an asset image?

**My code:**

```
//Function that decides if image is returned or not(If not, then it will show the default circle avator)
File getImageWidget() {
    if (_selectedImage != null) {
      return _selectedImage;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

//Function to set the image in the circle avatar
circleAva(){
return profileIconSelector(
   setProfileIconHighQuality(getImageWidget() ?? userDetails.profile_pic,
       userDetails.loginInitFrom),
       userDetails.name,
       SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 5);
}

//Function to get image from Camera or Gallery
getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    this.setState((){
      _inProcess = true;
    });
    File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    if(image != null){
      File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
          sourcePath: image.path,
          aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(
              ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
          compressQuality: 100,
          maxWidth: 700,
          maxHeight: 700,
          compressFormat: ImageCompressFormat.jpg,
          androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarTitle: "Cropper",
            statusBarColor: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          )
      );

      this.setState((){
        _selectedImage = cropped;
        _inProcess = false;
      });
    } else {
      this.setState((){
        _inProcess = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add asset images from your app. Asset images are images that you add to your project manually, but you can save the path to the image once it has been picked, then use `Image.file(File.fromUri(Uri.file(IMAGE_PATH)))`.

Comment: Is this will convert the asset image path to image file of File type ?? Actually, I have to use the **Image.asset widget** instead of **Image.file widget**. I have a image of File type that comes either from camera or gallery and I want it to convert from *File* type to *Image.asset* type.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I found the solution for this by myself.

In the case of the **Image.file()** widget, we have to provide the image of a *File* type.
And, In the case of the **AssetImage()** or **Image.asset()** widget, we need to pass the image path of *String* type.

> So the Solution to use Image of File type in **AssetImage()** or
> **Image.asset()** widget:

```
File _selectedImage = fetchedFromCameraOrGallery;

getImageWidget() {
    if (_selectedImage != null) {
      return CircleAvatar(
        radius: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 5,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage(
          _selectedImage.path,   //Convert File type of image to asset image path
        ),
      );
    } 
}
```

We have to simply use the **_selectedImage.path** that will convert the image file of *File* type to a valid Asset image path format.